# how to write inline azure function in azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I want to write **inline azure function** in azure **ARM template**.But i did not get any reference related to how to write inline azure function in azure ARM template.

Answer (score 2):

There's some pretty decent articles to find on that, like these from [Christos Matskas](https://cmatskas.com/)

- [Deploying Functions with ARM templates and inline code](https://cmatskas.com/deploying-functions-with-arm-templates-and-inline-code/)
- [azfunctionsinlinecode.json](https://gist.github.com/cmatskas/bedfc1c2a6b72d62e46b40d0b773f111#file-azfunctionsinlinecode-json-L81-L107) with the Function highlighted

Comment: You could take a look at [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/). It has 'Azure Subscriptions (management operations)' as an Event source, meaning that could be your trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd deployed the function using ARM template from the reference you provided. But I have one doubt, that how to **trigger** this function from ARM template. I basically need my function deployed and triggered from ARM template itself.